# Xcode iOS Project Fails When I Add C++ Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5.1

I have an OpenGL Xcode project, but when I want to add a `.h` and a `.cpp` file, it doesn't compile, even if I tell not to compile those files.

I get this error:

```
Apple Mach-O linker error

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_read_png_image", referenced from:
  read_png_texture(char const*, bool) in TextureUtilities.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: That's not enough information.  Where are those symbols located in the source files?  What references them?

Comment: Have you Googled the error message before posting the question? There are already lots of articles about this.

Comment: From my experiences I learning that `.cpp` don't compile, I've been used to just merge the `.h` and `.cpp` file to `.hpp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying cause of the error is that `read_png_image()` is a C function, but has been compiled with C++ linkage - which results in a 'mangled' symbol name that includes information about the types of the function's arguments.

The solution is to wrap the declaration of the function with `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C"
{
    void read_png_image(char const*, bool);
}
```

Presumably the `.cpp` file you added includes the declaration - possibly form a pre-compiled header.